# How to write now date with certain time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to create a date string like this, but its not in the format that I want.

I want ex.: `11.04.2020 11:00:00`, but i get: `04.11.2020 11:00:00`

```
var today = new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString() + " 11:00:00")
```

Comment: Your accepted answer returns a result different from your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const time = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', 'DD.MM.YYYY') + ' 11:00:00';

console.log(time)
```

Comment: doesn't match output : `11.04.2020 11:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a `native javascript` solution, you can use below snippet.

```js
const padLeft = (num) => (num < 10 ? "0" + num : num);
const formatteDate = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const [dd, mm, yy] = [now.getDate(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getFullYear()];
  return `${padLeft(dd)}.${padLeft(mm)}.${padLeft(yy)} 11:00:00`;
};
console.log(formatteDate());
```